# Using JQuery to hide columns with no data (including header) with same table ids

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xslt

I have a xslt template that creates HTML tables based off an element attribute. The template ids the table as `detailTable`. I can have several tables with this same id. I'm using jQuery to hide columns including `TH`s with no data. My problem is how do I get the jQuery to find each table. I can get the following code to work on one table, but it doesn't work if there is more than one table. jQuery code is below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#detailTable th').each(function(i) {
        var remove = 0;                           
        var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')')
        tds.each(function(j) { if (this.innerHTML == '') remove++; });

        if (remove == ($('#detailTable tr').length - 1)) {
            $(this).hide();
            tds.hide();
        }                           
    });
});
```

Comment: You should not use the same id attribute for different elements, use a class instead.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you have several tables with the same id? Try giving them a class instead and then you can do:

```
$('.detailTable th').each(function(i) {
    // code here...
});
```

Comment: Do what you will, but I try to not use classes as selectors unless it also is used for visual design (or if I have no other choice.) Setting the class for an element implies that it's design is defined by that class, which can be misleading to other devs who inherit your code.

Comment: This did not work.  I tried changing to class for table and updated the code to reflect changes.

Comment: The reason they have the same name is due to and XSLT template Im calling to create the tables based off an element attribute.

Comment: Can't you just change the XSLT template then?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you have multiple tables with the same ID. That's a no-no. Instead of using the `id` attribute, use `name` and change `$('#detailTable th')` to `$('table[name=detailTable] th')`

**EDIT:**

Since your XSLT is defining that the ID needs to be used, all that I can think to try (if you can't mod your XSLT) is to reference your tables in some other way. It might be a good idea to remove their ID's while you're at it - or change them to the `name` attribute instead, as I've done below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('table th').each(function(i) {
        var tbl = $(this).closest("table");
        if(tbl.attr("id") == "detailTable") {
            tbl.removeAttr("id").attr("name", "detailTable");
            var remove = 0;                           
            var tds = $(this).parents('table').find('tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')')
            tds.each(function(j) { if (this.innerHTML == '') remove++; });

            if (remove == ($('#detailTable tr').length - 1)) {
                $(this).hide();
                tds.hide();
            }                           
        }
    });
});
```

Note that I just wrote this in the SO editor, so it might need some tweaking but you should get the idea.

Comment: I tried this with no success.  I'm using xslt to generate the tables and the xslt names each table "detailTable".  That is the reason for the same names.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you have many tables with the same id.

Change the id to a class and try it.

You really shouldn't use the same id more than once.